# Check for duplicates on a repeated property in ndb, appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I am using `ndb.JsonProperty` with `repeated = True` to store a list of python dicts as an ndb entity. I like the list to contain no duplicates. I thought using something like following would work

```
    stored_list = TheList(id=list_id)
    current_list = stored_list.list_data
    current_list.extend(items) #items is a list of dicts that need to be newly added

    # check if the list contains duplicate items
    if len(current_list)!=len(set(current_list)):
        cached_list.list_data = current_list
        cached_list.put()
```

But `set(current_list)` wouldn't work because dicts are not hashable. I find out [some other python solutions](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/uniqifiers-benchmark) to do this but I thought the ndb might contain some feature to prevent repeated properties containing duplicate objects. [Doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#repeated) here contains no such information.

So my question, How to prevent repeated ndb properties containing duplicates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no NDB feature to support keeping repeated properties free from duplicates.  You might want to submit a separate question with the Python tag asking how to do this in general in Python.  But it's going to be O(N**2).

Comment: Thanks Guido, I'll go with one of the Python solutions I've found. Accepting your answer because there can't be a better solution.